# How to fix postfix set-permissions without user named root?

Tags: permissions, postfix

I'm trying to setup `Postfix` from [Entware](https://github.com/Entware/Entware) (a repo for embedded devices).

There is no SElinux involved and chroot is disabled in master.cf.

```
# postconf -n
command_directory = /opt/sbin
compatibility_level = 2
config_directory = /opt/etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /opt/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /opt/var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
default_database_type = cdb
inet_protocols = ipv4
mail_spool_directory = /opt/var/mail
manpage_directory = no
myhostname = domain.nl
mynetworks = 1.1.2.1,8.9.1.1
queue_directory = /opt/var/spool/postfix
shlib_directory = /opt/lib/postfix
smtputf8_enable = no
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

The issue is that `postfix set-permissions` isn't able to figure out the `root` user name. This distribution comes by default with a "root" user named "admin". At least I think that the user name is the issue, because of:

```
# postfix set-permissions
find: unknown user root
# ls -lah /opt/sbin/postdrop
-rwxr-xr-x    1 NewRootUser   root      246.8K Sep  8 22:33 /opt/sbin/postdrop
```

#### Regression

With the help of https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Steps_to_fix_permission_and_ownership_of_Postfix_binaries_manually_due_to_bug_on_zmfixperm is tried to fix the differences (`755` was already set):

```
# chown AdminUserName:postdrop /opt/sbin/postdrop
# chown AdminUserName:postdrop /opt/sbin/postqueue
# chmod g+s /opt/sbin/postdrop
# chmod g+s /opt/sbin/postqueue
```

Result:

```
# postfix check
postsuper: fatal: scan_dir_push: open directory defer: Permission denied
```

#### Question

How to make `postfix set-permissions` learn the `new root` user name?

Or how to manually do the steps that `postfix set-permissions` should do?

Or where in the [postfix source code](https://github.com/vdukhovni/postfix/blob/bfff4380a3b6fac2513c73531ee3a79212c08660/postfix/src/postfix/postfix.c) can one find the actions that are executed for flag `set-permissions`?

Comment: "renamed away from default "root".". This was a Known Bad Idea long ago. Most checks for `root`, or `toor`, or whatever, are actually checks for `UID = 0`, except for many hidden `USERID = "root "`. You'll never find them all. Renaming `root` is all problems, no benefit.

Comment: https://github.com/vdukhovni/postfix/blob/bfff4380a3b6fac2513c73531ee3a79212c08660/postfix/conf/post-install has one `chown` that brings `$user` in; apparently from the command-line, environment, or main.cf

Comment: the permissions are stored in the inode, if somehow you can modify it to gain access to /etc/postfix/main.cf and /etc/postfix/master.cf to modify it manually via accessing the place it's stored in from other OS

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69191/how-do-i-manually-modify-an-inode

Comment: or try using chmod from other operating system to give access to new renamed user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applications which expect and use user name `root` will understandably fail when there is no such user on the system. However, you can have more than one user with same UID. Usually, you should probably not configure the system with multiple user names with same UID, similarly as you should not rename `root` user.

You can add another UID 0 account, which has the username `root`. This possibly solves issues with applications which use user names instead of numeric UIDs. To add *an alias* `root` for UID 0 with disabled password and login, append following to `/etc/passwd`:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/false
```

Full syntax is explained in [`man 5 passwd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html).

Comment: With this `/etc/passwd` line, and a `ln -s /opt/sbin/sendmail.postfix /opt/sbin/sendmail`, I was able to `postfix set-permissions` and start postfix.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me echo other's point that renaming the `root` user is a bad idea.  That said, if you're set on doing it...

> Where in the postfix source code can one find the actions that are executed for flag set-permissions?

The command `postfix set-permissions` seems to be handled by `postfix/conf/postfix-script`, which in turn calls `post-install create-missing`:

```
set-permissions|upgrade-configuration)
    $daemon_directory/post-install create-missing "$@"
    ;;
```

https://github.com/vdukhovni/postfix/blob/bfff4380a3b6fac2513c73531ee3a79212c08660/postfix/conf/postfix-script#L376

https://github.com/vdukhovni/postfix/blob/bfff4380a3b6fac2513c73531ee3a79212c08660/postfix/conf/post-install#L245

You might have to search the repo for `"root"` and adjust anything that's expecting the administrator's username to be "root":

https://github.com/vdukhovni/postfix/search?p=3&q=root&unscoped_q=root

Comment: You answer says we are looking for `z`, and `a` leads to `b` leads to `c`, I am board, here are some links.

Comment: The question was where in the source is set-permissions handled. Providing a link to that point seemed like a legitimate answer.  Did I then trace that all the way down to some point where "root" is used? Clearly not.  Might the original author be able to do that with a concrete starting point? Hopefully.

Comment: But it does not create the missing file, rather the program fails with an error